# Spring bean prevent instantiation and use intended implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Given that I have two implementation of a Processor interface:

One Synchronous:

```
@Service("Synchronous")
@Primary
public class SyncProcessor implements Processor { ... }
```

Other Async:

```
@Service("Asynchronous")
public class AsynchronousProcessor implements Processor { ... }
```

The class that uses these services:

```
public class TestController{

    private final Processor processor;

    public TestController(final Processorprocessor) {
        this.processo r= processor;
    }

}
```

These services and the controller class sit in a common library framework maven project (say project A) and they get injected as dependencies in other projects (e.g. project B & C).

I want project B & C to use SyncProcessor by default which it does since it is annotated with @Primary.

However, the async service gets also instantiated and I would like to prevent that.

It should only be instantiated when in the projects B and C I do the following:

```
@Bean("customAsync")
public Processor processor(MyRepo repo,
                                   JobRunner jobRunner) {
    return new AsynchronousProcessor (repo, jobRunner);
}
```

The problem I am currently having is AsyncProcessor instance is getting created multiple times. How can I prevent this from happening?

The other issue I am having is that even when I create the bean in project B, the synchronous bean is being called. How can I use async?

Comment: Just remove the `@Service("Asynchronous")` annotation , it is not used as a `bean` in your `B and C ` and regarding the second question, you have to add the class that uses `customAsync` but you want `Synchronous` is used

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai that prevents multiple instances of async. But it still runs `Sync` processor when I provide `async` as a bean in `B and C`.

Comment: See the second part of my comment

Comment: its a controller class that sits in Project A and gets also injected in B and C. Project A injects Interface `Processor`, uses sync by default but should be overriden. So I am not sure what you mean. The class that uses it is in Project A

Comment: If you add your controller code  where you want `customAsync` injected

Comment: added, it refers to interface and there are two implementations, sync and async. When project B provides an Async bean, it should use that instead of Sync.

Comment: Why not use `@Profile`?

Comment: @daniu - I like the idea. can you show an example ?

Answer (score 0):

- By default, the following will inject your `@Primary` Processor

```
    @RestController 
    public class TestController{

      private final Processor processor;

      public TestController(final Processorprocessor) {
        this.processor = processor;
      }

   }
```

- If you want a processor other that `@Primary` injected, you have to specify it

```
    @RestController 
    public class TestController{

      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("customAsync")    
      private final Processor processor;

      public TestController(final Processorprocessor) {
        this.processor = processor;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Profile` so you can decide on startup what processor you use.

```
@Component
@Profile("sync")
public class SyncProcessor implements Processor {...} 

@Component
@Profile("async")
public class SyncProcessor implements Processor {...}
```

This way, your project can decide which will get created by setting the `spring.profiles.active` property accordingly (sync or async). It's not really intended for libraries, so your use case isn't as simple as you intend,.